# XSL split value into Array and check whether is more than 1

Tags: xslt

```
<books>
    <book>
        <title fiction="true">Happy Potter</title>
        <author>J. K. Rowling, Colman, Adman</author>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>

    <book>
        <title fiction="true">The Hobbit</title>
        <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
        <price>25.99</price>
    </book>
</books>
```

So I just want to check the authors is more than 1 or not. If do so, I would like to display first author name + et al at the end. If not, it just display the author name.

For example, the first author value is `J. K. Rowling, Colman, Adman`. Then I would like to display as `J. K. Rowling et al`.

So far, I only though about the split() but most of the resource was talking about using recursive-template. Due to I am new to XSL, I couldn't fully understand the code as they provide.

Any advises and helps will be much appreciate. Thanks.

**POST XSL FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
<h2>My Books Collection</h2>

<xsl:variable name="eligible-books" select="/books/book[title/@fiction='true' and price &lt; 30]" />

<xsl:for-each select="$eligible-books">     
    <span id="title"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></span><br/>
    <span id="author"><xsl:value-of select="author"/></span><br/>
    <span id="price"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></span><br/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>   

<span id="total">Total: <xsl:value-of select="sum($eligible-books/price)"/></span>

</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for recursion here. Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="author[contains(., ',')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ',')"/>
        <xsl:text> et al.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book>
    <title fiction="true">Happy Potter</title>
    <author>J. K. Rowling et al.</author>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title fiction="true">The Hobbit</title>
    <author>J.R.R. Tolkien</author>
    <price>25.99</price>
  </book>
</books>
```

---

### Added:

In your stylesheet, change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="author"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains(author, ',')">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(author, ',')"/>
         <xsl:text> et al.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: I have a question. What is the `@*|node()` about? Based on my understanding, the template could be a something like Function in java right? It can declare the functionalities and applied wherever you like. Am I correct?

Comment: See the explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT

Comment: Hi Michael, I had posted my XSL file by editing my post. I am trying to apply your method into my XSL. But I couldn't fit in. Any advise?

Comment: @JackWong If you're outputting HTML, then the identity transform template has little relevance for you. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: I try implemented with other way round. I am using the `<xsl:choose>` method in my <span id="author"> tag. It is work, but I don't know why it capture the Happy Potter as well.

Comment: Yeah. That's the approach I am trying to add. But just get some minor error of cataching value.

Comment: You can see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/ehVYZMD. Note that I am using `substring-before(author, ',')`, not `substring-before(., ',')` as you seem to be.

Comment: Thanks Michael. ;D